# Repository test failed while cloning - Bitbucket

Tags: android, git, android-studio, kotlin, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a repository hosted in Bitbucket using Android Studio. However, Android Studio did not asked me for entering user credentials (My Username and Password).
Secondly, when I clicked "Test" to test the link with the repository, it is showing me "Authentication failed error" which means that the test was failed.

How can I resolve this?
Git is installed on my system and recognised by Android Studio.

Comment: Are you trying to clone over HTTPS or SSH?

Comment: @JimRedmond HTTPS